# SQLAlchemy: How to work with allocation table?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am a little confused. I am trying to start with SQLalchemy (ORM). I have brought you a small executable example-code. Well you see three tables in total. In short: many-to-many-relationship. *products* and *orders* are 'normal' tables. *order_product* is a allocation table. You also see I insert some records in tables of *products* and *orders*. Up to now all records is saved in each table. It works like a charm. And now the problem. How do I save the IDs in the allocation table? What does the design look like? How to work with the allocation table? So far the allocation table is empty.

**Update - Specifed question**

Most examples show how to work with the association pattern, but only, when everthing happens at the same time. For instance, a user saves a product at first and second he saves an order and finally he relate two diffeent things (allocation table). But... imagine... a user saves a product... one hour later he saves an order. And one day later, he would like to relate the products and orders. In my imagination, I have to find out the ID of the order and then have to find out the ID of the product... an now, I can can relate it, right? But how?

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

#memory_url = 'sqlite:///:memory:')

#sqlite_url = 'sqlite:///test.db'

mysql_url = '{dbms}+{dbdriver}://{dbuser}:{dbuser_pwd}@{db_server_host}:{dbport}/{db_name}'.format(
           dbms='mysql', dbdriver='pymysql', dbuser='root', dbuser_pwd='', db_server_host='localhost', dbport=3306, db_name='test')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(mysql_url, echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()


class Order_Product(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'order_product'
  order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('orders.id'), primary_key=True)
  product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
  quantity = Column(String(30))

  order = relationship("Order", backref=backref("order_product", lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan" ))
  product = relationship("Product", backref=backref("order_product", lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan" ))

  def __init__(self, order, product, quantity):
    self.order = order
    self.product =  product
    self.quantity = quantity

class Product(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'products'
  id = Column(Integer,  primary_key=True, unique=True)
  name = Column(String(80))

  orders = relationship("Order", secondary="order_product")

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Order(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'orders'
  id = Column(Integer,  primary_key=True, unique=True)
  name = Column(String(80))

  orders = relationship("Product", secondary="order_product")

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

prod1 = Product(name="Oreo")
prod2 = Product(name="Hide and Seek")
prod3 = Product(name="Marie")
prod4 = Product(name="Good Day")


session.add_all([prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4])
session.commit()

order1 = Order( name = "First Order")
order2 = Order( name = "Second Order")
order3 = Order( name = "Third Order")
order4 = Order( name = "Fourth Order")

session.add_all([order1, order2, order3, order4])
session.commit()
```

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

Comment: I have specified my question.

Comment: Just add a new `Order_Product` instance like any other model instance, with the related order and product set to the correct ids/instances. For example `session.add(Order_Product(order_id=oid, product_id=pid, quantity=42))`, if you have the ids at hand and don't feel like fetching the instances of order and product.